# AngularJS with Chrome browser TTFB is high

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

When using http://localhost:8080/birt/index.html#/test-script, the application is working fine means TTFB time is in milliseconds. But when I am using http://ipaddress:8080/birt/index.html#/test-script, TTFB is very high (around 8-15 seconds). The issue is only in the Chrome browser, Firefox it is working fine.

We are using AngularJS with a Spring and Hibernate framework back-end.

Comment: Is caching disabled/enabled in all browsers?

Comment: enabled for both the browser.